# Проблема с реализацией регистрации/авторизации на домене второго и третьего уровней

Tags: php, ajax, сессия

Регистрацию/Авторизацию осуществляю с помощью суперглобального массива `$_SESSION` данные отправляю асинхронно `ajax` на домен второго уровня `example.ru`, там выполняется php-скрипт регистрации и авторизации. По такому же принципу реализована корзина. Сайт имеет поддомен `sub.example.ru`. 
в `.htaccess` прописано `php_value session.cookie_domain ".example.ru"`
сессию начинаю в обоих контроллерах(контроллер 1 - `.example.ru`, контроллер 2 - `sub.example.ru`) таким образом:
`if (!session_id()) {
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
    ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.ru');
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.ru');
    session_start();
}`
Кука `PHPSESSID` с идентификатором передаётся между доменом о поддоменом и обратно. Проблема 1: если осуществлять регистрацию и авторизацию находясь на `sub.example.ru` (напомню - `ajax` отправляет данные на `.example.ru`) то `$_SESSION['auth']` создаётся, но после обновления страницы пропадает.
Проблема 2: если осуществлять регистрацию и авторизацию находясь на `sub.example.ru` (напомню - `ajax` отправляет данные на `.example.ru`) и при этом существует `$_SESSION['cart']`, то `$_SESSION['auth']` создаётся вне сессии, в которой создана `$_SESSION['cart']`, после обновления страницы `$_SESSION['auth']` также  пропадает. НО! Если осуществлять регистрацию/авторизацию с `.example.ru` и при этом существует `$_SESSION['cart']`, то `$_SESSION['auth']`создаётся в этой же сессии, после обновления никуда не пропадает и сохраняется на `sub.example.ru`. В чём проблема?

Comment: PHPSESSID точно создаёться с правильным доменом?

Comment: @Naumov да, PHPSESSID  домен - .site.ru с точкой.

Comment: @Naumov пробовал ещё передавать идентификатор через ajax: `var SID = $.cookie('PHPSESSID');$.ajax({
                                url: 'http://site.ru/',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                    PHPSESSID: SID, // дальше остальной код` ничего не изменилось.